# Selecting the negative expression

Tags: equation-solving, filtering, expression-manipulation, assumptions, asymptotics

Let `Theta`,`t` be real variables and `Phi` an expression of `Theta`,`t`.
I want to solve `Phi==0` w.r.t. `t` assuming `Theta` is in a neighbourhood of $\pi^-$.

```
In[0]:= Phi=-Sin[Theta] + t*Cos[Theta]*(-t + (2 + t)*Sin[Theta])
```

I use the AsymptoticSolve function (so any prior assumptions on `Theta`,`t` are not used) :

```
In[1]:= sols = AsymptoticSolve[Phi==0,t->0,Theta->Pi,Reals,Direction->"FromBelow",Assumptions->t<0]
Out[1]:= {{t -> Pi - Sqrt[Pi - Theta] - Theta}, {t -> Pi + Sqrt[Pi - Theta] - Theta}}
```

What we can see is that it returns two solutions, however only the first component `{t -> Pi - Sqrt[Pi - Theta] - Theta}` is a negative solution and Mathematica didn't remove the other one.

How can I select only the negative solutions?
I used the following :

```
Select[sols,#<0&]
```

but Select do not use the variable `$Assumptions`.

Comment: `Select[sols // Flatten, (t /. # /. Theta -> Pi - 0.01) < 0 &]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Select negative solutions.

```
Select[sols, 
 Resolve[Exists[ϵ, ϵ > 0, 
    ForAll[s, 
     Pi - ϵ < s < Pi, (t /. # /. Theta -> s) < 0]]] &]
```

> `{{t -> π - Sqrt[π - Theta] - Theta}}`

- Select positive solutions.

```
Select[sols, 
 Resolve[Exists[ϵ, ϵ > 0, 
    ForAll[s, 
     Pi - ϵ < s < Pi, (t /. # /. Theta -> s) > 0]]] &]
```

> `{{t -> π + Sqrt[π - Theta] - Theta}}`